# Cannot import qgis.core. DLL load failed

Tags: python, pyqt, environment-variables, gis, qgis

I writing a small standalone GIS application, with some tools from QGIS and GUI made with PyQt. Im trying to import qgis modules like `qgis.core` and `qgis.gui` into my python programm, and failing hard no matter how i try.

Im using:

- Python 3.4 (`C:\Python34`) + PyCharm
- QGIS 2.2 (`C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2`)

I set my environment-variables this way:

- `PYTHONPATH`, i added `C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2\apps\qgis\python\`
  (there is other items before that, if its matters)
- `Path`, i added `C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2\apps\qgis\bin` - where all qgis 
  .dll files seems to be.**1**

I read every single topic i found on google, every related question on stackoverflow, set my environment-variables in a million of different ways, nothing seems to work. I get this error message every time.

```
C:\Python34\python.exe F:/PyCharm_Projects/Project_1/Testing_Area.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCharm_Projects/Project_1/Testing_Area.py", line 3, in <module>
    import qgis.core
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS_2.2\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If i just run QGIS desktop, and execute `import qgis.core` in it's buildin python console, it works, no errors.

I'm a new user, so i think i may be missing somthing simply. So please if you know what may be wrong, tell me. I dont understand, i suppose to write my standalone application based on QGIS inside QGIS python console? Can't i use my Python 3.4 with all my needed modules installed?

**1**. I'm not sure to which variable (system `Path`, or user `PATH`) i should add this. I tried both and none of them worked.

**2**. PyCharm give me this warning every time. Maybe it will help. [PyCharm Warning](http://s10.postimg.org/tq8kuqxo9/Error.png)

Comment: Check the 'bitness' of your installations. You may be mixing 32 and 64-bit versions.

Comment: People have told me, that i cant run QGIS modules from python 3.4 and i should use Python 2.7 that comes with QGIS. Maybe this is the case.